# Check if a file exist

Tags: c, file

How can I check if a file exists in APPDATA without using the full path ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    if (access("%APPDATA%\\changzhi_leidianmac.data", F_OK) != -1)
    {
        printf("File Found......");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File not found !!!!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>


int main(void)
{
    //  Define the trailing portion of the file path.
    static const char FileName[] = "\\changzhi_leidianmac.data";

    //  Get the value of environment variable APPDATA or fail if it is not set.
    const char *APPDATA = getenv("APPDATA");
    if (!APPDATA)
    {
        fputs("Error, the environment variable APPDATA is not defined.\n",
            stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("APPDATA is %s.\n", APPDATA);

    //  Figure the space needed.  (Note that FileName includes a null terminator.)
    size_t Size = strlen(APPDATA) + sizeof FileName;

    //  Get space for the full path.
    char *Path = malloc(Size);
    if (!Path)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Error, unable to allocate %zu bytes of memory for file path.\n",
            Size);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //  Copy APPDATA to the space for the path, then append FileName.
    strcpy(Path, APPDATA);
    strcat(Path, FileName);
    printf("Full file path is %s.\n", Path);

    //  Test whether the file exists and report.
    if (0 == access(Path, F_OK))
        puts("The file exists.");
    else
    {
        puts("The file does not exist.");
        perror("access");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [getenv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-wgetenv?view=msvc-170)

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *appdata = getenv("APPDATA");
    ...
    ...
}
```

And later use `snprintf`.

Answer (score -3):

C does not have any provisions for accessing env variables. You need to use either a library or system commands to get the data.

Comment: wait... what about `getenv(3)`?

Comment: `getenv` is specified in C 2018 7.22.4.6.

Comment: *C does not have any provisions for accessing env variables.* Fundamentally, that displays a complete lack of thought.  If environment variables could not be accessed by programs, why would they even exist?

Comment: `getenv` *is* a library function, even a standard library.I never said it can't be done.
Nevertheless, I hope the person asking the question found a good answer.

Comment: @thripper: The standard C library is a part of C, and `getenv` is a provision that C has for accessing environment variables.